# Alien Invasion struggling

Tags: python

I'm working on the Alien Invasion game from the Python Crash course book, but i can't run the game.

Here's my code:

```
# Alien Invasion game
import sys

from time import sleep


import pygame


from settings import Settings

from game_stats import GameStats

from button import Button

from ship import Ship

from bullet import Bullet

from alien import Alien

from scoreboard import Scoreboard


class AlienInvasion :
    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize the game, and create game resources'''
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        # Create an instance to store game statistics and create a scoreboard
        self.stats = GameStats(self)
        self.sb = Scoreboard()

        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230) 
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

        # Make the Play button
        self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")

        # Make the difficulty level buttons.
        self._make_difficulty_buttons()

    def _make_difficulty_buttons(self):
        """Make buttons that allow player to select difficulty level."""
        self.easy_button = Button(self, "Easy")
        self.medium_button = Button(self, "Medium")
        self.difficult_button = Button(self, "Difficult")

        # Position buttons so they don't all overlap.
        self.easy_button.rect.top = (
            self.play_button.rect.top + 1.5*self.play_button.rect.height)
        self.easy_button._update_msg_position()

        self.medium_button.rect.top = (
            self.easy_button.rect.top + 1.5*self.easy_button.rect.height)
        self.medium_button._update_msg_position()

        self.difficult_button.rect.top = (
            self.medium_button.rect.top + 1.5*self.medium_button.rect.height)
        self.difficult_button._update_msg_position()

    def run_game(self):
        '''Start the main loop for the game'''
        while True :
            self._check_events()

            if self.stats.game_active:
                self.ship.update()
                self._update_bullets()
                self._update_aliens()
                
            self._update_screen()

    def _update_bullets(self):
        '''Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets'''
        # Update bullet positions
        self.bullets.update()
        # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()

    def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
        '''Respond to bullet - alien collisions'''
        # Remove any bullets and aliens that have collided
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
        self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)

        if collisions :
            for aliens in collisions.values():
                self.stats.score += self.settings.alien_points
            self.sb.prep_score()
            self.sb.check_high_score()

        if not self.aliens :
            # Destroy existing bullets and create new fleet
            self.bullets.empty()
            self._create_fleet()
            self.settings.increase_speed()

            # Increase level.
            self.stats.level += 1
            self.sb.prep_level()

    def _update_aliens(self):
        '''
        Check if the fleet is at an edge,
        then update the positions of all
        aliens in the fleet
        '''
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

        # Look for alien - ship collisions
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
            self._ship_hit()

        # Look for aliens hitting the bottom of the screen
        self._check_aliens_bottom()

    def _ship_hit(self):
        '''Respond to the ship being hit by an alien'''
        if self.stats.ships_left > 0 :
            # Decrement ships_left, and update scoreboards
            self.stats.ships_left -= 1
            self.sb.prep_ships()

            # Get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets
            self.aliens.empty()
            self.ship.center_ship()

            # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
            self._create_fleet()
            self.ship.center_ship()

            # Pause
            sleep(0.5)
        else:
            self.stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    def _check_events(self):
        '''Respond to keypresses and mouse events'''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)
                self._check_difficulty_buttons(mouse_pos)

    def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
        '''Start a new game when the player clicks Play'''
        button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)

        if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active :
            # Reset the game statistics
            self.stats.reset_stats()
            self.stats.game_active = True
            self.sb.prep_score()
            self.sb.prep_level()
            self.sb.prep_ships()
            
            self.aliens.empty()
            self.bullets.empty()

            self._create_fleet()
            self.ship.center_ship()

            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def _check_difficulty_buttons(self, mouse_pos):
        """Set the appropriate difficulty level."""
        easy_button_clicked = self.easy_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        medium_button_clicked = self.medium_button.rect.collidepoint(
                mouse_pos)
        diff_button_clicked = self.difficult_button.rect.collidepoint(
                mouse_pos)
        if easy_button_clicked:
            self.settings.difficulty_level = 'easy'
        elif medium_button_clicked:
            self.settings.difficulty_level = 'medium'
        elif diff_button_clicked:
            self.settings.difficulty_level = 'difficult'

    #def _start_game(self):
        '''Start a new game'''
        # Reset the game statistics
        #self.stats.reset_stats()
        #self.stats.game_active = True
        #self.sb.prep_score()
#
        # Get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets
        #self.aliens.empty()
        #self.bullets.empty()

        # Create a new fleet and center the ship
        #self.create_fleet()
        #self.ship.center_ship()

        # Hide the mouse cursor
        #pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        '''Respond to keypresses'''
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_p and not self.stats.game_active:
            self._start_game()

    def check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        '''Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group'''
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed :
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _create_fleet(self):
        '''Create the fleet of aliens'''
        # Make an alien
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available.space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        # Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on the screen
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                            3 * (alien_height)- ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // 2 * (alien_height)

        # Create the full fleet of aliens.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
            
    def _create_alien(self, alien_number):
        '''Create an alien and place it in the row'''
        self._create_alien(alien_number)
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_wdith * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        '''Respond appropriately if any alien has reached an edge'''
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        '''Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction'''
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
        '''Check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen'''
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.midbottom > screen_rect.bottom:
                # Treat this the same as if the ship got hit
                self._ship_hit()
                break

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        # Draw the score information
        self.sb.show_score()

        # Draw the play button if the game is inactive
        if not self.stats.game_active:
            self.play_button.draw_button
            self.easy_button.draw_button()
            self.medium_button.draw_button()
            self.difficult_button.draw_button()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

```
# Ship
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Ship(Sprite) :
    shipimage = r'C:\Users\basti\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Images and sprites\Spaceships\Spaceshipt.png'
    with open(shipimage) as f:
        def __init__(self, ai_game):
            '''Initialize the ship and set its starting position'''
            super().__init__()
            self.screen = ai_game.screen
            self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
            self.settings = ai_game.settings
        
            # Load the ship and get its rect
            self.image = pygame.image.load
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

            # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
            self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
            self.x = float(self.rect.x)

            # Movement flag
            self.moving_right =  False
            self.moving_left = False

            # Ship settings
            self.ship_speed = 1.5
        
        def blitme(self):
            '''Draw the ship at its current location.'''
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        def update(self):
            '''Update the ship's position based on the movement flag'''
            # Update the ship's x value, not the rect.
            if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right :
                self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
            if self.moving_left and self. rect.left > 0 :
                self.x -= self.settings. ship_speed

            # Update rect object from self.x
            self.rect.x = self.x

        def center_ship(self):
            '''Center the ship on the screen'''
            self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
            self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

```
# Scoreboard
import pygame.font

from pygame.sprite import Group

from Ship import Ship

class Scoreboard :
    '''A class to represent scoring information'''

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        '''Initialize scorekeeping attributes'''
        self.ai_game = ai_game
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.stats = ai_game.stats

        # Font settings for scoring information
        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

        # Prepare the initial score images
        self.prep_score()
        self.prep_high_score()
        self.prep_level()

        # High score should never be reset
        self.high_score = 0

    def prep_level(self):
        '''Turn the level into a rendered image'''
        level_str = str(self.stats.level)
        self.level_image = self.font.render(level_str, True,
                    self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

        # Position the level below the score
        self.level_rect = self.level_image.get_rect()
        self.level_rect.right = self.score_rect.right
        self.level_rect.top = self.score_rect.bottom + 10

    def prep_score(self):
        '''Turn the score into a rendered image'''
        rounded_score = round(self.stats.score, -1)
        score_str = "{:,},".format(rounded_score)
        score_str = str(self.stats.score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True,
                    self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

        # Display the score at the top right of the screen
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20

    def prep_ships(self):
        '''Show how many ships are left'''
        self.ships = Group()
        for ship_number in range(self.stats.ships_left):
            ship = Ship(self.ai_game)
            ship.rect.x = 10 + ship_number * ship.rect.width
            ship.rect.y = 10
            self.ships.add(ship)

    def show_score(self):
        '''Draw scores, level, and ships to the screen'''
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
        self.ships.draw(self.screen)

    def prep_high_score(self):
        '''Turn the high score into a rendered_image'''
        high_score = round(self.stats.high_score, -1)
        high_score_str = "{:,}".format(high_score)
        self.high_score_image = self.font.render(high_score_str, True,
                                self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

        # Center the high score at the top of the screen
        self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_image.get_rect()
        self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.high_score_rect.top = self.score_rect.top

    def check_high_score(self):
        '''Check to see if there's a new high score'''
        if self.stats.score > self.stats.high_score:
            self.stats.high_score = self.stats.score
            self.prep_high_score()
```

When i run alien_invasion, i get this error :

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\basti\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Alien Invasion\Alien Invasion.py", line 321, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
  File "C:\Users\basti\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Alien Invasion\Alien Invasion.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.sb = Scoreboard()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ai_game'
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Could someone help me correct it ?
P.S. : Also, I don't understand why we use the self argument in `self.ship = Ship(self)` and `self.alien = Alien(self)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*. There is no good reason to throw hundreds of lines of code into a question.

Comment: The definition of `Scoreboard.__init__` links like this: `def __init__(self, ai_game):`. It requires the `ai_game` argument, but your code (`self.sb = Scoreboard()`) doesn't provide it.

Comment: You apparently need to pass an instance of `AlienInvasion` to `Scoreboard`.  That's what `Ship(self)` and so on are doing (here `self` is the instance of `AlienInvasion` being set up.

Comment: @mr_Oxam for your PS, the reason is that by passing the `self` instance (of the `AlienInvasion` class) to the constructor of the `Ship` class (its `__init__` method), so that it can interact with the board (for example it stores `ai_game.screen` into its `self.screen` attribute, which is used later in `blitme`). It is a way for the game to provide the gamestate to the ship.